# Messing with Encoding and XslCompiledTransform

Tags: xml, xslt, httpwebrequest

im messing with the encodings.

For one hand i have a url that is responding me in UTF-8 (im pretty sure thanks to firebug plugin).

Im opening the url reading the content in UTF-8 using the following code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

For other hand i have a transformation xslt sheet with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <br/>
            hello
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This xslt sheet is saved in UTF-8 format too.

I use the following code to mix the xml with the xslt:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();

transformer.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("xslt\\xsltsheet.xslt");  
XmlWriterSettings xmlsettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlsettings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
transformer.Transform(xmlreader, null, writer);   

return writer;
```

Then after all im render in the webbrowser the content of this writer and im getting the following error:

> The XML page cannot be displayed 
>   Cannot view XML input using style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and
>   then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again later.
>
> Switch from current encoding to
>   specified encoding not supported.
>   Error processing resource
>   'http://localhost:2541/Results....
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
> ```

Im wondering where is finding the UTF-16 encoding take in count that:

- All my files are saved as UTF-8
- The response from the server is in UTF-8
- The way of read the xslt sheet is configured as UTF-8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Jose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your writer is causing this to be written out, since the `Encoding` property returns the UTF-16 encoding. Instead of using a `StringWriter` (which is UTF-16 in memory) you could initialize an `XmlTextWriter` instance to use UTF-8 with a `MemoryStream` as backing store.

**Edit:** Another way to work around the issue is to inherit from `StringWriter` and override the `Encoding` property to return the encoding you like (e.g. UTF8 in your case). This idea is from a [blog post written by Robert McLaws](https://weblogs.asp.net/rmclaws/32534).

```
public class UTF8StringWriter: StringWriter {
    public UTF8StringWriter() {}
    public UTF8StringWriter(IFormatProvider formatProvider): base(formatProvider) {}
    public UTF8StringWriter(StringBuilder sb): base(sb) {}
    public UTF8StringWriter(StringBuilder sb, IFormatProvider formatProvider): base(sb, formatProvider) {}

    public override Encoding Encoding {
        get {
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}
```

You're not alone with this problem... see for instance the [MSDN community comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(VS.80).aspx?PHPSESSID=6c7e47uec18v8n3121a6p001h4) (on the bottom) or the following [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118072238/http://geekswithblogs.net/pakistan/archive/2005/08/23/50884.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, transformer.OutputSettings))
{
    xsl.Transform(xmlreader, writer);
}
```