# XslCompiledTransform uses UTF-16 encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding

I have the following code, which I want to output xml data using the UTF-8 encoding format. but it always outputs data in UTF-16 :

```
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

            xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString), new XmlReaderSettings()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            writerSettings.Indent = true;

            xslt.Transform(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXMLToTransform)), XmlWriter.Create(sb, writerSettings));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The XML output will contain a header that is based on the encoding of the stream, not the encoding specified in the settings. As strings are 16 bit unicode the encoding will be UTF-16. The workaround is to suppress the header and add it yourself instead:

```
writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
```

Then when you get the result from the StringBuilder:

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Old post but I have a question. I tried this and it worked for my situation but I'm wondering if this work-around actually changes the encoding? My usage is sending some xml data to another system. The system accepts the xml if the declaration says utf-8 but not utf-16. I feel that the actual encoding of the xml string has not changed and I'm just getting lucky that it works.

Comment: @JamesGardner: It doesn't change the encoding, it makes the header match the actual encoding that is used to create the XML.

Answer (score 7):

If you use a `MemoryStream` in place of the `StringBuilder`, the `XmlWriter` will respect the encoding you specify in the `XmlWriterSettings`, since the `MemoryStream` doesn't have an inherent encoding like the `StringBuilder` does.

Comment: Also handy https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858095/5269981