# XSL:Output with encoding=utf-8 not working with XslCompiledTransform

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, encoding

I have the output element in xslt file as:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent ="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" standalone="no" encoding="utf-8" version="1.0" />
```

I am using `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` class to transform an xml document into another one. The transformed xml that is generated has `encoding="utf-16"` despite  instructing that to be utf-8.

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("prices.xsl");
XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
BookPrice obj = new BookPrice();
xslArg.AddExtensionObject("urn:price-conv", obj);
StringWriter wr = new StringWriter();
xslt.Transform(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(GetFileData("books.xml"))), xslArg, wr);
writeToFile("output.xml", wr.ToString());
```

Comment: I found one solution at http://forums.asp.net/t/1436663.aspx?Xslt+XML+Encoding+utf+8+problem
But why is XslCompiledTransform class ignoring the <xsl:output> ?

Comment: Another one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858024/messing-with-encoding-and-xslcompiledtransform?rq=1